# Python: Dumbo Import Error

Tags: python, easy-install, hadoop-streaming

I'm trying to import [Dumbo](https://github.com/klbostee/dumbo/wiki) for the first time and ran into this error:

```
In [1]: import dumbo
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-d77979db43c5> in <module>()
----> 1 import dumbo

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\dumbo\__init__.py in <module>()
     21 """
     22
---> 23 from dumbo.core import run, main, Error, Job, Program
     24 from dumbo.backends.common import Counter  # for backwards compatibility

     25 from dumbo.lib import *

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\dumbo\core.py in <module>()
     18 import os
     19 import types
---> 20 import resource
     21 import copy
     22 from itertools import groupby

ImportError: No module named resource
```

I installed dumbo as suggested in its [github](https://github.com/klbostee/dumbo/wiki) wiki both ways.

Through :`$ python ez_setup.py -z dumbo` and : `env/bin/easy_install -z dumbo`.

Any ideas on how to fix it or correctly locate the `resource module`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`resource` module is a UNIX specific module, i.e. it works only on *NIX systems. I can see that you work on Windows, in this case Dumbo will not work. The package should explicitly say that it is UNIX specific (because of resource dependency).